# Left join return multiple row instead of one

Tags: mysql, sql

i have three tables (tblOrder, tblOrder_Item, tblCredit) but when im using left join, the **tblCredit** show 3 row instead of 1.

**tblOrder**

```
idOrder    date         idUser
1          2020-01-01   1
2          2020-02-02   2
3          2020-03-03   3
```

**tblOrder_Item**

```
idOrder_Item   qty   price   idProduct   idOrder
1              3     30      1           1
2              2     20      1           1
3              5     50      1           2
```

**tblCredit**

```
idCredit   amount   idOrder
1          15       1
2          10       2
```

**the actual result is:**

```
idOrder   priceTotal   credit   remainingPayment
1         130          **30**    100
2         250          10        240
```

**but my expected result is:**

```
idOrder   priceTotal   credit   remainingPayment
1         130           15        115
2         250           10        240
```

how to fix this? do i need to move the tblCredit.amount to tblOrder instead? thank you

**sorry i forgot the link. here is the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ead83/1**

Comment: You haven't told us *how* you're joining the tables. Please update your post with your SQL.

Comment: Please Paste your SQL query in question which you tried.

Comment: sorry i forgot the link. here is the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ead83/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It there is never more than one credit per order, you can use aggregation as follows:

```
select
    o.iOrder,
    sum(oi.price * qty) priceTotal,
    coalesce(c.amount, 0) credit,
    sum(oi.price * qty) - coalesce(c.amount, 0) remainingPayment
from tblOrder o
inner join tblOrder_Item oi on oi.iOrder = o.iOrder
left join credit c on c.iOrder = o.iOrder
group by o.iOrder, c.amount
```

I used a `left join` when bringing the `credit` table: presumably, some orders might not have a credit yet.

On the other hand, if an order may have several credits, then you need to aggregate the price and credit per order in subqueries, and then join the results with the orders table:

```
select
    o.idOrder,
    oi.priceTotal,
    coalesce(credit, 0) credit,
    oi.priceTotal - coalesce(credit, 0) remainingPayment
from 
    tblOrder o
    inner join (select iOrder, sum(price * qty) priceTotal from tbllOrder_Item group by iOrder) oi
        on oi.iOrder = c.iOrder
    left join (select iOrder, sum(amount) credit from tblCredit group by iOrder) c 
        on c.iOrder = o.iOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find that `union all`/`group by` does what you want:

```
select iOrder, sum(priceTotal) as priceTotal,
       sum(credit) as credit,
       sum(priceTotal) - sum(credit) as remainingPayment
from ((select oi.iOrder, oi.price * oi.qty as priceTotal, 0 as credit
       from tblOrder_Item oi
      ) union all
      (select c.iOrder, 0 as priceTotal, c.amount as credit
       from tblCredit c
      )
     ) oic
group by iOrder;
```